# Multiple Aws CodeDeploy applications in a newly added instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I think i've done something wrong while designing my aws infrastructure.
Actually i have one autoscaling group with one ec2 instance.

On this instance there are 6 laravel projects that are associated to 6 applications in aws CodeDeploy, so when i want to update the version i simply update using codedeploy.

Issues comes when the autoscaling group adds instances to the group, all my codedeploy applications are deployed to the newly created instance and it fails with this message:

> One or more lifecycle events did not run and the deployment was unsuccessful. Possible causes include:
>   (1) Multiple deployments are attempting to run at the same time on an instance;

So... what's the best way to get this to work ?

Answer (score 3):

AWS recommends associating a single deployment group to an ASG and consolidate deployments to a single deployment for proper scale out. Each deployment group associates a lifecycle hook with ASG through which ASG will notify deployment-group when scale-out events occur. Parallel deployments (in your case 6) will be prone to codedeploy timeouts (5 -60 min) and codedeploy agent running on ec2 can take one command at time.

If each of your app takes less time (<60 mins), you may want to consolidate them to a single application and deploy via codedeploy hooks. Else would suggest to use different asg for app.

Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/under-the-hood-aws-codedeploy-and-auto-scaling-integration/

list lifecycle hooks:

```
 aws autoscaling describe-lifecycle-hooks --auto-scaling-group-name <asg_name> --region <region>
```

If launch of new ec2 goes infinite loop of terminate and launch,you can remove lifecycle hooks

```
aws autoscaling delete-lifecycle-hook --lifecycle-hook-name <lifecycleName> --auto-scaling-group-name <asg_name> --region <region>
```

Comment: Ok so if i consolidate all apps into one and than remove all single apps application hooks i can keep the ability to update one app a time and every time an instance is added to the ASG apps are automatically deployed

Comment: Automatic deployments will consider last successful deployment for that deployment group, If you update your apps individually keeping consolidated app hooks, old app revisions may get deployed when scale out happens. If you prefer using single ASG, consolidate all applications into one and control individual updates using hooks (such AfterInstall/start/stopApplication). How to do this depends on your application nature.

Comment: Oh I see... Would be cool if in some way, aws could add a sequential deploy when scale out happens. The whole deploy process in my case should at maximum least 5 minutes. By using multiple ASG you mean also using multiple EC2 instances ?

Comment: Yes. each app on different ASG with one ec2 .

Comment: Uhm, that's not very cheap. At the moment i use a t2.medium instance, because the small have not enough network performance, so i should keep on using that kind of instance.